# Creating SQL Server 2008 R2 DTSX from C# - Exception from HRESULT: 0xC0048021

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, ssis

I'm creating a dtsx from C# (.NET 4.0) but when I try add the OLEDB Source into the data flow and is time to execute the ProvideComponentProperties step, I recieve the following error in VS2010:
Exception from HRESULT: 0xC0048021

This is part of the code I'm using:

```
//add SQL destination
IDTSComponentMetaData100 SQLDestination = dataflowTask.ComponentMetaDataCollection.New();
SQLDestination.ComponentClassID = "DTSAdapter.OleDbSource.1";
// Set the common properties            
SQLDestination.Name = "SQLDestination";
SQLDestination.Description = "SQL destination";
CManagedComponentWrapper SQLDestComponent = SQLDestination.Instantiate();
SQLDestComponent.ProvideComponentProperties(); // The error happens here
```

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 and C# .NET Framework 4.0

Comment: Could it be a GAC issue? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.dts.pipeline.wrapper.idtsdesigntimecomponent90.providecomponentproperties(v=sql.90).aspx http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlintegrationservices/thread/c74758d2-e3f7-4d4d-9d8a-9684c05b8628

Answer (score 0):

You are limited to VS2008 and .NET 3.5 for SQL2008 R2.